# MongoDB - Filter and count large collections for statistics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid with Rails. I have a collection called "datasets" with around 600,000 documents. Inside of each dataset there is a key "files" that may or may not exist. Inside of files there is an array of objects (files). I need to get all datasets that have files and then get a count of all files on those datasets. This is what I have but it is throwing an error saying it exceeds the maximum document size:

```
total = Dataset.collection.aggregate([
  { '$project' => { files: 1 }},
  { '$unwind' => '$files' },
  { '$group' => {_id: "$_id", count: {'$sum' => 1} } }
])
```

I can get it to work using the following but it is just too slow and doesn't really use the power of the db at all:

```
datasets_with_files = Dataset.where(:files.exists => true)

count = 0
datasets_with_files.each do |dataset|
  count += dataset.files.count
end

count
```

So basically I need to know A. What the best type of query is to do this, and B. If aggregation is the best way, how to deal with the document exceeding the maximum size so I can perform queries like this.

SOLUTION:

I got this working without needing a cursor or disk usage:

```
Dataset.collection.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { files: { '$exists' => true }}},
  { '$unwind' => '$files' },
  { '$group' => { _id: nil, total_files: { '$sum' => 1 }}}
])[0]['total_files']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly project the size of an array field using [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size), so in the shell you could do this as:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {files: {$exists: true}}},
    {$project: {count: {$size: '$files'}}}
])
```

In Ruby it would look like:

```
@coll.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { files: { '$exists' => true } } },
  { '$project' => { count: { '$size' => '$files' } } }
])
```

Include the `cursor` option to overcome the 16MB size limit on the results:

```
@coll.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { files: { '$exists' => true } } },
  { '$project' => { count: { '$size' => '$files' } } }
], cursor: {})
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. The problem is when I run an aggregation query it throws the document size error:
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
 "code" : 16389,
 "ok" : 0
}

Do you know what to do with something like that? Thanks again.

Comment: @sturoid As long as you're using MongoDB 2.6.x you can set the cursor option to overcome the 16MB limit.  See update.

Comment: That is awesome. I tried the last one but I get:
"exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'cursor'

Would that have something to my version of Mongoid or something? I have mongo 2.6.7 on my machine.

Comment: @sturoid Make sure the `cursor` object is passed as a separate parameter and not part of the pipeline array.

Comment: Sorry I copy and pasted what you have and it still throws that error. Do you have any idea why it would?

Comment: @sturoid Maybe mongoid uses a different syntax, I was trying this with the standard ruby driver for MongoDB.